# How to decide to show the result of a query with an external condition

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this query which works well

```
SELECT tb.id, tb.nom, tb.proddate, tb.qty, tb.stockrecno, 
SUM(IF((status>0 AND tb.id=sd.prodid),quantite,0)) AS rq FROM " + TableName + " AS tb 
JOIN StockData AS sd  ON (tb.id = sd.prodid AND sd.matcuisine = 3) 
GROUP BY tb.id, tb.nom, tb.proddate, tb.qty, tb.stockrecno ORDER BY proddate DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET @Myid"
```

I added a variable in my program ShowZero which is designed to show if the result of tb.qty-rq is zero or not. ShowZero = true shows even if the result of tb.qty-rq = 0, if ShowZero = false display only if tb.qty-rq>0

I added this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ShowZ", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = ShowZero;
```

And I added at the end of my query WHERE ((@ShowZ) OR (!@ShowZ AND tb.qty - SUM(IF((status>0 AND tb.id=sd.prodid),quantite,0)) >0)) // The alias rq is not accepted here I'don't know why ?

but this gives an error.

Is there a way to do it in this query?

PS:OFFSET @Myid is an index that let me to control last record read.

I use .NET 3.5 and XAMPP v.3.2.1 c# 2008 express

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Herei is the link off error (The syntax WHERE is at the end of query I tried before GROUP Before Limit but it does not work) http://www.turcguide.com/stack/error1.jpg